# Can I install cuda if I have Intel Graphics?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, nvidia, intel

I want to use NVIDIA's CUDA-Toolkit for a project, but I have an Intel(R) Iris Xe Graphics (Windows 11 Pro). On installing Nvidia Graphics GeForce Game Ready, I am getting the following error

> This Nvidia graphics driver is not compatible with this version of Windows. This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware

Comment: You can install it but it will not do anything since CUDA only works on NVidia graphics cards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, NO.

Intel doesn't support CUDA drivers yet in any of its GPUs.
Although you can find some possible workarounds like [this](https://github.com/vosen/ZLUDA).

If your primary motive is for machine learning based tasks, you can still consider using Google Colab or its likes.

[Additionally, most 12th generation Intel processors have an additional Gaussian and Neural Accelerator (GNA), which can help accelerate ML workloads, although not as fast as a GPU]

Answer (score 8):

Generally CUDA is proprietary and only available for Nvidia hardware.

One can find a great overview of compatibility between programming models and GPU vendors in the [gpu-lang-compat](https://github.com/AndiH/gpu-lang-compat) repository:

> [SYCLomatic](https://github.com/oneapi-src/SYCLomatic) translates CUDA code to SYCL code, allowing it to run on Intel GPUs; also, Intel's [DPC++ Compatibility Tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/dpc-compatibility-tool.html) can transform CUDA to SYCL

For context, DPC++ (Data Parallel C++) is Intel's own CUDA competitor. It is based on SYCL which is a newer, higher level standard by the Khronos Group, which also standardized e.g. OpenCL.

### Edit: TensorFlow

As the question is tagged with TensorFlow, the right solution might be to use the [Intel® Extension for TensorFlow*](https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-tensorflow) (not sure what the "*" is about) which lets TensorFlow use Intel GPUs. Sadly the [Hardware Requirements](https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-tensorflow/blob/main/docs/install/install_for_xpu.md) do not specify Intel® Iris Xe Graphics:

> Verified Hardware Platforms:
>
> - Intel® Data Center GPU Max Series, Driver Version: 736
> - Intel® Data Center GPU Flex Series 170, Driver Version: 736
> - Experimental: Intel® Arc™ A-Series

So this might not help OP.

If you have some custom CUDA code, the previously mentioned tools might still be of value. Of course you will not need any Nvidia drivers.