# Is it possible to use Intel Iris GPU with Pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I have installed Anaconda and installed a Pytorch with this command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

There was no option for intel GPU, so I've went with the suggested option. However, I don't have any CUDA in my machine. The only GPU I have is the default Intel Irish on my windows. Is it possiblr to run any Deep learning code on my machine and use this Intel GPU instead?

I have tried to run the follwing but it's not working:

```
def get_hwacc_device():
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        
        print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
        print('CUDA memory usage:')
        print('Allocated:', round(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024**3,1),'GB')
        print('Cashed:   ', round(torch.cuda.memory_reservrd(0)/1024**3,1),'GB')
        
        device = torch.device('cuda')
        
    #Windows
    elif hasattr(torch,"backends") and\
         hasattr(torch.backends, "mkl") and\
         torch.backends.mkl.is_available():
        
        device = torch.device('mkl')
        
    print("GPU device is:", device)
    
    return device
```

ERRPR:

```
---> 18     device = torch.device('mkl')
     20 print("GPU device is:", device)
     22 return device

RuntimeError: Expected one of cpu, cuda, ipu, xpu, mkldnn, opengl, opencl, ideep, hip, ve, fpga, ort, xla, lazy, vulkan, mps, meta, hpu, mtia, privateuseone device type at start of device string: mkl
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question.  But whether yes or no, it has nothing to do with CUDA.

Comment: Hi @Robert Crovella  Yes, I know that is kind of unrelated to Cuda, but I included the cuda tag, becaus I installed "pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia". So, I am also wondering what might happen as a result? Because there's no cudea whatsoever on my machine

Comment: Related: [Can I install cuda if I have Intel Graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75566837/10107454)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of an extension for running Pytorch on Intel GPU.
https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/xpu/1.13.120+xpu/tutorials/examples.html.
According to the examples, the device should be xpu if you running on Intel GPU.

Answer (score 1):

#### Intel has provided some notes for using Pytorch on its GPUs

> The Intel extension, Intel® Optimization for PyTorch extends PyTorch with optimizations for an extra performance boost on Intel hardware. Most of the optimizations will be included in stock PyTorch releases eventually, and the intention of the extension is to deliver up-to-date features and optimizations for PyTorch on Intel hardware, examples include Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (Intel® AVX-512) Vector Neural Network Instructions (AVX512 VNNI) and Intel® Advanced Matrix Extensions (Intel® AMX).

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/getting-started-with-intel-optimization-of-pytorch.html

Comment: thanks for the link. This suggest lots of change inside the existing code though?? I just wanted to use my previous running codes on colabs, inside my local machine, and just by changing one line of code related to device. Is it not possible? Right?

Comment: Not possible, I am afraid.